# How to call an ActiveX method through java when control doesn't allow automation (com4j/jacob)?

Tags: java, activex, jacob, com4j

I have to integrate to an ActiveX control that doesn't allow for automation (no `IsInvokeAllowed` implemented to return true) through Java.

Up to now, the best java libraries for COM integration in my research are *com4j* and *jacob*.

When trying to invoke a method on a control that doesn't allow for automation, I get a **[Catastrophic Failure](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189065)** exception while calling methods on controls that allow automation just work.

Is there a way to call methods on ActiveX objects that doesn't allow for automation with Java (through com4j/jacob/other)?

Unfortunately getting the ActiveX object vendor to enable automation on their control is not an option.